# How to import and bundle lodash using rollup?

Tags: lodash, rollup

I am unable to import lodash with rollup. I have tried some different configuration but haven't found anything that works.

Using lodash

```
import compose from "lodash/fp/compose";
compose(removeDocumentInformation)(document.saveXML());
```

Rollup config

```
  {
    input: "src/renderer/renderer.tsx",
    output: [{ dir: "app/build", format: "es", sourcemap: true }],
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      replace({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        // Gets rid of console warning to install React Dev Tools for a better development experience
        __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__: "({ isDisabled: true })",
      }),
      commonjs({
        namedExports: {
          "node_modules/react/index.js": [
            "useEffect",
            "useState",
            "Component",
            "PureComponent",
            "PropTypes",
            "createElement",
            "cloneElement",
            "Children",
          ],
          "node_modules/react-dom/index.js": ["render"],
          "node_modules/lodash/fp/compose.js": [],
        },
      }),
      resolve({
        mainFields: ["module", "main", "jsnext:main", "browser"],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      }),
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: ["src/renderer/index.html", "src/renderer/styles.css"],
            dest: "app/build",
          },
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Error seems unrelated to issue but disappears if I remove lodash

```
src/renderer/renderer.tsx → app/build...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
crypto...
url...
path...
http...
https...
net...
tls...
querystring...
stream...
events...
asserts...
zlib...
fs...
buffer...

[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
node_modules\mime-db\db.json (2:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is resolved or not since it has been asked for more than one year.
the project seems a bit more complicated than just the 'lodash', it has react and use typescript. better to provide the entire project env on github maybe.
or you can just try @rollup/plugin-json